# JavaFx ObservableSet adapter

Tags: java, listview, javafx, observablelist

I've a JavaFx client. I'm using as model a bean that has a ObservableSet as field.
I want display these data into a ListView and I can't change the kind of my field to a ObservableList.

I think I should write a sort of adapter in order to adapt my ObservableSet to a ObservableList (because ListView requires that).

Using ObservableList the code is:

```
listView.setItems(myBean.getMyEntitiesList());
```

I need to set items in the same manner because the data list cames lazy from the server so I need that the Ui updates when data arrives.

Someone is able to give me some idea on how implements such kind of adapter?

Answer (score 3):

You can add a listener to the set and update the list when it changes:

```
ObservableList<T> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList(myBean.getMyEntitiesList());

myBean.getMyEntitiesList().addListener((Change<? extends T> change) -> {
    if (change.wasAdded()) {
        items.add(change.getElementAdded());
    }
    if (change.wasRemoved()) {
        items.remove(change.getElementRemoved());
    }
});

listView.setItems(items);
```

Obviously replace `T` with whatever the actual type of the elements in your list/set are.

Comment: Good hint, I tried it but the line throws an Exception: Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.sun.javafx.collections.ObservableSetWrapper$1.hasNext(ObservableSetWrapper.java:214)
 at java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(AbstractCollection.java:343)
 at javafx.collections.ModifiableObservableListBase.addAll(ModifiableObservableListBase.java:99)
 at javafx.collections.FXCollections.observableArrayList(FXCollections.java:341)

Comment: Presumably you know how to debug a null pointer exception. There's obviously no way anyone can debug it from the snippet of the stack trace you have shown. If you [edit] your question with a [MCVE], I can put the answer in context for you.

Comment: You are right @James_D, unfortunately there are limited chars for comments and add it in the question It did not seem like a good idea.

Comment: So the obvious solution would be to create a [MCVE] :).

Comment: You are right again. I've try to semplify my code and make an MCV example :-)